# How do I recreate this user behavior through Locust?

Tags: locust

The users on my site follow these actions:

- Send requests of Type A arbitrarily (meaning, I am satisfied with using something like `between(1.0,5.0)`
- Send requests of Type B exactly every second (but must follow Type A)
- Send requests of Type C exactly every second (but must follow Type B)
- Send requests of Type D arbitrarily (but must follow Type C).

My idea was:

- Create a `TaskSet` for each request type (so that types B and C will have `wait_time = between(1.0,1.0)`)
- Use `self.interrupt()` in each request type once the request sets are exhausted.

However, how do I establish order (for example, B must happen only after A has finished)?

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = [TypeA, TypeB, TypeC] #current idea, but this doesn't guarantee order between A,B,C.
    wait_time = between(1.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Cant you just use a single task set with between(1.0,5.0) and manual time.sleep(1) calls between requests?

Comment: @Cyberwiz that is indeed what I ended up doing. Thanks!